# encryption of SSRS subscription emails and attachments

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs

Is it possible to set up an SSRS e-mail subscription, with an attachment, that is encrypted?

**POST ANSWER-ACCEPT UPDATE:** Does the **SMTPUseSSL** switch in the RSReportServer.config file help me at all?

**ONE MORE UPDATE**: No, the **SMTPUseSSL** switch does not get me there.  I have validated the answer below [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159155%28v=sql.100%29):

`The default e-mail delivery extension does not provide support for digitally signing or encrypting outgoing mail messages.`

Comment: Try this link http://www.databasepotential.com/ Actually i got some errors while using the tool but no one is responding to the emails from this vendor. Thanks
Mahesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not out of the box as far as I am aware, and if you need to distribute reports to external parties this is a bad idea as they will all have to install third party encryption software (incurring licensing and support costs).  It will also put your help desk people into the job of babysitting all the users as they forget their keys.

You're much better off providing a secure portal (this can be done with Sharepoint if you have this) and emailing out links to the reports.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have a number of constraints.  We are not on the latest version of SharePoint, in which I could distribute straight to SharePoint and remove the need for the e-mails.  The distribution is, indeed, all internal but our policies dictate that the e-mails/attachments be encrypted.  I'm not optimistic that this is possible, but I figured I'd float the question.  :)

Comment: The other option would be to put them on a file share and with AD managed security.

Comment: +1, @jgardner04 - that's actually what we currently do.  :)  I am exploring other options.

Comment: The encryption is a tough requirement.

Comment: You're better off serving them through a portal than trying to roll out encrypted email infrastructure.  That gets you into babysitting everyone's encryption keys, and when they lose the keys they lose the encrypted reports, so you've got to stash plaintext copies of them somewhere as well.

Comment: The problem is then I end up babysitting everyone's access to the portal, but that's a different challenge for a different day.  We really need to upgrade our SharePoint instance - many of my headaches disappear then.  Thanks for the input!